# NSString alloc outside autorelease pool creates mysterious memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsstring, autorelease, dealloc

the following error is produced at runtime when manually allocating and releasing memory:

```
objc[10430]: Object 0x109014b60 of class __NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
```

I searched the internet but usually these errors are caused by not releasing memory or using autoreleased shorthands... I cannot find any unreleased memory, nor am I using an autoreleased shorthand... Hoping you can help!

My code is:

```
#import "try.h"

@implementation try

- (try*)initWithSwing
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self tellAboutSwing:YES];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) tellAboutSwing: (BOOL) swing {

    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@ %@", @"Do we have a swing on our playground?", (swing ? @"Yes" : @"No")];


    // cast to a char
    const char *c = [s UTF8String];
    [s release];    
    printf("%s", c);

}

- (void) dealloc {
    printf( "Deallocing Playground\n" );
    [super dealloc];
}

int main(void) {
    try *t;
    t = [[try alloc] initWithSwing];
    [t release];
}

@end
```

Putting an autorelease pool inside the instance method fixes the issue, but that shouldn't be necessary with `NSString alloc`. While I am new to Objective-C I think I have grasped the concept of owning and releasing variables, yet I am having difficulty finding my error here.

Here's my .h file:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface try : NSObject
- (void) tellAboutSwing: (BOOL) swing;
@end
```

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Regards,

Robert

Comment: Just because *you* don't use autorelease doesn't mean the *frameworks* don't. The NSString class can autorelease whatever it wants, whenever it wants (as long as it owns it). This is why you are always supposed to have an autorelease pool when using objective-c.

Comment: I've not found this to be the case.  I've certainly had the above message, but it's always been due to an obvious cause.  In this case UTF8String call is the likely culprit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC `-[NSString UTF8String]` uses an autoreleased `NSData` to actually hold the bytes of the UTF-8 C string.

Update: Here's a simpler way using just C functions:

```
- (void) tellAboutSwing: (BOOL) swing {    
    printf("%s %s", "Do we have a swing on our playground?", (swing ? "Yes" : "No"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! That was it! Now just for the learning part (I could probably use an `UTF8String` from the beginning to avoid the autorelease); how could I circumvent the creation of an autoreleased `NSData` object, while still casting `NSString` to char? Can I take ownership of the NSData object? `[c retain]` causes a compiler error, why? Like I said, I am new to Objective-C, and I am trying to get a solid understanding, most documents on MM don't go into these specifics. Thanks in advance, Robert!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use an autorelease pool? That said, you can use the oldschool C functions instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use an NSAutoreleasePool. It's normal to have one and at some point you won't find an alternative which is not creating autoreleased objects internally.

I think you should check out some tutorials and guides on memory management and the basics, otherwise you will have a hard time understaning Objective-C.

For example, there is a great course on iTunesU which is free and explains the basics of Objective-C.